# Condition for convergence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence

Let $A \in \mathbb{R^{m\times{n}}}$ with full row rank. Let $B=I-\lambda A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Determine the set of values of $\lambda$ for which $\exists \lim_{k \to +\infty}B^k$.

If the subordinate matrix norm of $B(lubB)$ is $<1$ then the limit exists (I am using $\|\cdot\|_2$). With this norm, $lub(B)=\sqrt{\lambda_{max}(B^TB)}$.

We have $B^TB=B^2$. So, the eigenvalues of $B^TB$ are $1$ and $(1-\lambda)^2$.

Therefore, $max(1,(1-\lambda)^2)=\begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if } \lambda \in [0,2]\\
    \sqrt{(1-\lambda)^2}=1-\lambda,              & \text{if} \lambda \in (-\infty,0)
\end{cases}$

Finaly, we have that $lub(B)<1$ if and only if $\lambda \in (2,\infty)$. So, $\exists \lim_{k \to +\infty}B^k$ if and only if $\lambda \in (2,\infty)$.

I'm not sure if I did it right. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Your argument doesn't sound right. Let $m=n$ and $A=I$. Then $B=(1-\lambda)I$. Clearly $\{B^k\}$ does not converge for any $\lambda\in(2,\infty)$.

The general problem actually boils down to the above case. Let $A=U\pmatrix{S&0_{m\times(n-m)}}V^T$ be a singular value decomposition, where $S$ is an $m\times m$ positive diagonal matrix and $U,V$ are orthogonal matrices. Then
$$
B=I-\lambda V\pmatrix{I_m&0\\ 0&0}V^T=V\pmatrix{(1-\lambda)I_m&0\\ 0&I_{n-m}}V^T.
$$
Therefore the powers of $B$ converge if and only if the powers of $1-\lambda$ converge. Hence the domain of convergence is $-1<1-\lambda\le1$, i.e. $\lambda\in[0,2)$.

Comment: Alternatively, since $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A$ is a projection, it is similar to $I_m\oplus0$ and hence $B$ is similar to $(1-\lambda)I_m\oplus I_{n-m}$.